# Remove extra white space but leave one space remaining in string

Tags: ruby, string, whitespace, gsub, strip

I want to be able to take in a string with the word 'WUB' placed randomly throughout it, and remove those instances replaced with white space.

Ex. "WUBWUBWUBWEWUBWUBAREWUBWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBWUBMYWUBFRIENDS"

turns into... 
WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIENDS

However the problems stands that I receive that with extra white space for each 'WUB.' How can I take out the extra white space and retain only one single white space?

```rb
def song_decoder(song)
  song.gsub!(/WUB/, " ")
  song.strip!
  print song
  return song
end

song_decoder("WUBWUBWUBWEWUBWUBAREWUBWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBWUBMYWUBFRIENDS")

# above is test case
```

Answer (score 2):

`/WUB/` gets all the "WUB" in the string, so if there are some consecutive ones, you'll have two white spaces, and using strip on the result, just would remove all whitespaces, so wouldn't be what you expect.

You could get any "WUB" as groups and replace them with ' '. As this specific result leaves you just with an initial whitespace (first character), `lstrip` would deal with that:

```
str = 'WUBWUBWUBWEWUBWUBAREWUBWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBWUBMYWUBFRIENDS'
p str.gsub(/(WUB)+/, ' ').lstrip
# "WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIENDS"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the squeeze method!

```rb
def song_decoder(song)
  song.gsub!(/WUB/, " ")
  song.strip!
  song.squeeze!(" ")
  print song
  return song
end
```

This does exactly what I need. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expression:

```
"WUBWUBWUBWEWUBWUBAREWUBWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBWUBMYWUBFRIENDS".
  split('WUB').reject(&:empty?).join(' ')
#⇒ "WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIENDS"
```